# Share link to facebook from Android Application with out image

Tags: android

Am posting image and url to facebook wall by using folowing code

```
          private void postToWall() {
    if (facebook != null) {
        if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("picture", "imageurl");

            b.putString("caption", "Testing");
            b.putString("description", "Testing in android");
            b.putString("name", "naveen");

            b.putString("link", "http://funmango.com/");
            try {
                String strRet = "";
                strRet = facebook.request("/me/feed", b, "POST");
                JSONObject json;
                try {
                    json = Util.parseJson(strRet);
                    if (!json.isNull("id")) {
                        Log.i("Facebook", "Image link submitted.");
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Facebook", "Error: " + strRet);
                    }
                } catch (FacebookError e) {
                    Log.e("Facebook", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Facebook", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But my requirement is if there is no image i want to post only text and link to wall ,

Thanks in advance